# ReactJs + Redux : how to do blockUI easy just like jQuery BlockUi?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In redux store, I can use `Thunk` for asyncs state : `fetching_data` and do `render()` to block elements.

but i think it makes a lot of work to do. if I have many components to `blockUi`.

**Are there any best practice to make it easy like**

```
 $('#container-1').blockUi();   
 $('#container-1').unBlockUi(); 

  $('#container-2').blockUi();  
  $('#container-2').blockUi();
```

Comment: Why do you need to block many components? How it related to async data fetching?  Do you want to block UI while you fetching data? Please provide more information, it is not clear what are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [react-block-ui](https://availity.github.io/react-block-ui/) which has a specific component for blocking and unblocking based on actions dispatched in redux (https://availity.github.io/react-block-ui/components/reduxblockui/)

It's simple with react-block-ui.

```
<ReduxBlockUi block="REQUEST_START" unblock="REQUEST_SUCCESS">
  <p>The Thing I am Blocking</p>
</ReduxBlockUi>
```

Now, when the `REQUEST_START` action is dispatched the section will start blocking, and when `REQUEST_SUCCESS` is dispatched, it will stop. You can change these action names to what you are using.

There is a middleware piece, see the example and documentation on https://availity.github.io/react-block-ui/components/reduxblockui/ for more information.